# "Denn spätestens jetzt" --- was will man damit sagen?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Als ich heute eine kleine Geschichte las, habe ich diesen Ausdruck gefunden, dessen Bedeutung für mich nicht klar ist:

> *Denn **spätestens** jetzt kommt mein Kollege und fragt mich, ob ich etwas trinken möchte.*

Die Bedeutung von *spätestens* ist klar für mich, aber in diesem Satz will mir diese Bedeutung nicht passen. Gibt es vielleicht eine passende englische Übersetzung für *spätestens jetzt*?

Ist die Bedeutung vielleicht nur *später* (later)?

Answer (score 3):

"spätestens" means "at the latest" but here it might help to see it as "at that point or earlier", which is the same. 
The example sentence means:

> Because if he hasn't come already, he'll definitely come now and ask ...

As a context I could imagine someone who has problem getting home in time after work because he or she usually ends up in a bar with colleagues.

EDIT: Sorry for the English. I was under influence of the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

"Spätestens jetzt" means "At the latest now" or "up to here". You use it to say that something is going to happen any time soon, and whatever happened just before is the straw that broke the camel's back.

For example, imagine two people arguing. Person A says something, but to person B these arguments are all bogus. You know person B is going to explode when he cannot take it anymore. You could say "A kommt gerade mit Argument X an. B springt auf und verlässt den Raum, denn spätestens jetzt hat B die Nase voll."